# How is the physical memory on external storage device interpreted as files by Linux OS?

Tags: operating-system

I understand that physical memory is a uniform array of flipflops (transistors) from the hardware perspective. But while operating the computer, we can see that the memory is represented as files represented by a file system. What is the underlying mechanism the OS uses for such an interpretation.

Comment: **Too broad** question. In short, "uniform array of flipflops" is firstly interpreted as *sequence of bytes*. This interpretation is hardware-specific. Then every concrete filesystem interprets this sequence of bytes as hierarchical structure contained files and directories. You may start with reading about *filesystems*.

Comment: Thank you. I will start with files systems

Answer (score 0):

Memory devices are usually divided into 2 categories : character devices and block devices. With a character device, the driver communicates with its controller on byte boundary, that is to say, the device can read & write specific byte addresses (Like RAM/ROM, certain types of NOR-based flash memories). Block devices on the other hand, communicates with the driver on block boundary & therefore not every byte is addressable but is accessed within a chunk of data (Magnetic based memories like hard drives & NAND-based flash memories, probably with Flash Translation Layers included on chip).
The important part to understand is that an extensive level of modularity and abstraction layers is needed to provide a file illusion on a high level.
 First, the device has a controller interface from which we can access the device's internal memory Without knowledge of how this memory is actually implemented in the inside, for instance, a flash device could behave exactly like a magnetic device on the interface level (Both implementing a SATA interface or PCIe). Theoretically, one driver for one type can be used with a completely different type if the two types are using the same communication protocol (Logical architecture, internal registers, same interface ..etc).
The second part is the specific file system driver and operating system's I/O subsystem, which will invoke the low drivers for the specific device but before that the manage a high level of abstraction (Logical blocks/pages/units, specific data structures) & they may implement different caching & prefetching techniques, on this level we can even make a character device look like a block device & vice-versa.
And finally, on the very high level, there is the virtual file system (aka VFS) layer that makes all filesystems and all devices look the same : a simple file with open read & write in arbitrary positions with simple system calls using wrapper functions from standard libraries like `GLIBC`.
The conclusion is that there are many abstraction layers involved to implement such an illusion, on both the hardware level (through controllers/interfaces & special devices) and the software level (low level drivers that communicate with the device's controller, filesystem drivers, buffering, caching & virtual file systems) & there are things that relates everything with each other. For instance, buses, chipsets, caches & many many other things. That's the big orchestra that makes this wonderful world.